# Richfaces 4.2.3 Fileupload not working

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I´m trying to upload some files with the richfaces fileupload.

This is my .xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
        xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition
            template="/WEB-INF/templates/application/main-template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="contentheader">
                <h:outputText value="#{messages.incoming_malfunction_header}" />
            </ui:define>
            <h:form id="controls_form">
            <ui:define name="contentbody">
                    <rich:fileUpload maxFilesQuantity="2" immediateUpload="true"
                        fileUploadListener="#{isiDataTransferPM.uploadListener}"
                        listWidth="280px">
                        <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render="controls_form" />
                    </rich:fileUpload>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

This is my uploadeListener:

public void uploadListener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {

```
final UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
if (selectedEntity.equals(ENTITY_WORK)) {
//addToList
}
```

This is my web.xml config:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.maxRequestSize</param-name>
        <param-value>10000000</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I use the following libraries:

```
jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.7.Final-redhat-1.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.2.3.Final.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.2.3.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.2.3.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.2.3.Final.jar
```

Debbuging the code shows, that the listener is called. But after calling this listener,the progress bar of the fileupload shows still 0 %. Nothing happens anymore.

Any Ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Try `<a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="controls_form" />`.

Comment: The listener is called after the file is uploaded, so the progressbar should be at 100% by then. What server do you use?